# Sound Input Works in Audacity but not in PavuControl

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, skype, microphone, audacity

I have a weird problem with my sound input.
Namely the internal microphone of my laptop does not work with Skype, but it does work with Audacity. When I tried to configure everything, I installed PavuControl and I had to find out, that the Input Device section did not record any audio.

When I use Audacity, I can select any option for a microphone device (default, sysdefault, pulse, HDA Intel PCH: CX20588 Analog (hw:0,0) ) for it to work.
When I do a Skype test call, and I run PavuControl with it, under the recording section it says the input is from Built-In Audio Analog Stereo, but it does not work.
When recording in Audacity, the same thing is shown.

I use Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Answer (score 1):

In Pavucontrol , "**input device**" tab,  you may have 2 devices: choose "built in analog", and check that "internal mic" is selected there.

Normally, the switching between internal/external mic is automatic  . If it is broken, you can try to plug an external  mic (or a headphone, just for the test)  in the mic jack, and see if "pavucontrol" input device change.

You can also try to test other profiles in pavucontrol "configuration" tab.

If it stills bad,  you can try to reset Pulseaudio config by copying and running this command in a terminal:

`rm -r ~/.config/pulse; pulseaudio -k`

Comment: Hey, thanks for your help. Your suggestions did not work, however I figured out something else: It does work perfectly with an external mic, and I figured out where the problem is: I had to mute one channel of the mic input, see: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver/+bug/1002978

Comment: Thank you, @user2750563, Post this as an answer to get an upvote.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in a previous comment, try muting the right input channel in `pavucontrol` under the `Input Devices` tab by clicking the unlock channels button (the icon to the left of the set as fallback icon) and then dragging the right slider to 0. As strange as it is, in my case pulseaudio could only pick up on specifically the sound of the letter "s" before doing this.

[More information from the original link here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver/+bug/1002978).