# Microphone input volume too low in Cheese, Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, microphone, input, pavucontrol

Microphone volume is too low to be heard in Cheese and Skype but works ok when I record with Audacity and when I do this:

```
vlc pulse://
```

I dual-boot Windows 10 and the microphone works ok in Skype on Windows. I have used `pavucontrol` and `gnome-alsamixer` to check microphone input volume levels (not enough reputation to post screenshots)

I use a Lenovo G50-80. More info about my system:

```
$ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: CX20751/2 Analog [CX20751/2 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

$ pactl list sinks short
0   alsa_output.pci-0000_00_03.0.hdmi-stereo    module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 44100Hz   SUSPENDED
1   alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo  module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 48000Hz   SUSPENDED

$ lspci | grep Audio
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Audio Controller (rev 09)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP High Definition Audio Controller (rev 03)

$ uname -r
3.16.0-46-generic

$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the suggestion in [the comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/525545/sound-input-works-in-audacity-but-not-in-pavucontrol#comment740236_525968) at [Sound Input Works in Audacity but not in PavuControl](https://askubuntu.com/questions/525545/sound-input-works-in-audacity-but-not-in-pavucontrol):

> If your internal mic is either completely silent (no signal), or you
>   can possibly pick a very small sound, with much background noise, even
>   though you have set gain to maximum, there is something you could try.
>
> Install the pavucontrol application, start it and go to the "Input
>   Devices" tab. Unlock the channels (there is a keylock icon), then mute
>   the right channel while keeping the left channel at the volume you
>   want. If the internal mic is now working correctly, you have an
>   inverted internal mic, so that your right channel cancels out the left
>   one.

source: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver/+bug/1002978